# Excel macro to convert HTML entities to text

Tags: html, excel, text, html-entities

I have a huge Excel file that contains the result of an online survey.  The person who built the survey messed up the formatting in several respects, and the mess-up I need to take care of first is converting HTML entities to regular text.

From what I can see only two HTML entities are used, `&#44;` and `&quot;` but the document is over 12,000 rows so I cannot be sure there are no other HTML entities used... and if other HTML entities are used I want them converted to text as well.

I have successfully made a macro to convert the two HTML entities I mentioned into text, but I don't know how to make the macro execute on the entire file (i.e. I have to hold down on the macro hot key to make it execute... and it is taking forever).

If there was a macro already available to do what I want that would be great because I could also use a modified version of it for my next task of arranging all the columns and rows in the proper order.

**UPDATE:**

This is the version of my macro that searches for `&#44;`.  It works, I just have to hold down on the hot key which takes forever.  If I could make this run on the entire Excel file that would be great, and then I can just adjust the macro for each HTML entity until I have eliminated them all.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' HTML_Converter Macro
'

'
    Cells.Find(What:="&#44;", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="&#44;", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Find(What:="&#44;", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your macro code ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a backup of the workbook.

Open the VBA editor by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Double-click "This Workbook" in the treeview at left under the workbook that you are working with.

Copy and paste the following:

```
Sub UnescapeCharacters()

    ' set this to match your case
    sheetname = "Sheet1"

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = Me.Worksheets(sheetname)

    For Row = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For Column = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            Dim cell As Range
            Set cell = sheet.Cells(Row, Column)

            ' define all your replacements here
            ReplaceCharacter cell, "&quot;", """" 'quadruple quotes required
            ReplaceCharacter cell, "&#44;", ","
        Next Column
    Next Row

End Sub

Sub ReplaceCharacter(ByRef cell As Range, ByVal find As String, ByVal replacement As String)

    Dim result As String
    cell.Value = replace(cell.Text, find, replacement, 1, -1)

End Sub
```

This just iterates over every cell in the specified worksheet and replaces everything you define. The provided code replaces the two character codes you mentioned.

You can run it as a macro, or just place the caret in the "UnescapeCharacters" subroutine and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: awesome.  Where is the caret (`^`) you are talking about?

Comment: @typoknig Sorry, I just meant the cursor. You can run a subroutine from the VBA editor by pressing F5, and it will run whatever routine your cursor is in. There is also a little "play" button in the default toolbar, I believe.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am new to Excel macros (and VB Script), but they are pretty powerful!  I changed one little thing about your code and it worked perfect... you just forgot the `;` at the end of the HTML entities.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a Excel addin that has this feature:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGEc6tLaKvA