# Is there a faster way Excel macro to convert non-standard characters to HTML entities?

Tags: vba, text, excel, html-entities

I found [this really useful snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649693/excel-macro-to-convert-html-entities-to-text/4649871#4649871) by **[Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114994/jay)** which helped me to convert text *to* HTML entities in Excel (by switching the before and after) in prepration for a CSV export.

e.g. `ReplaceCharacter cell, "€","&euro;"  'euro`

However, as per second comment on that thread, this isn't the most efficient method - for instance, I have a document with about 90 rows and about 13 columns. Being very new to VBA/macros, my understanding of how the script works is that it scrolls through each cell, finds the characters and replaces them.

This particular method took just under 1:00 minute (55 seconds) - which I timed by putting the msgbox popup after it finished running.

Whilst this is still reasonable (I could go away and make a cup of tea in a minute) it won't be the same if there were 1000 rows instead, so I was wondering if anyone could suggest any improvements or alternative methods of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Are you looking only for a faster Excel Macro, or are you open to other tools as well?

Comment: @KatieK: I suppose I was thinking about a faster Excel Macro, but I am all ears for other suggestions too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

2002 rows in 3 seconds...

```
    Cells.Replace What:="€", Replacement:="&euro", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

Just stack a couple of those on top of each other and you'll be good! (No loop needed!)